# Remove Gaps Justified text with Hyphenation

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to remove the **gaps** on justified text using hyphens with jQuery?

Not repeating a bunch of hyphens.

I'm using the following plugin:

http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

If the font is monospaced, then you can predict the width of a line and justify the text as you like (by inserting "-" in spaces).

Comment: I can get the width of the container, then how do I know where to insert the hyphen?

Comment: You have to know the width of a char (how many chars per line) and then it's all math.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but... If you mean remove space between specific words, you just need to use a single dash between those words.

In CSS, `text-align: justify` does not add any additional spaces, but modifies the word-spacing per line. If you want to not justify your text, then just use `text-align: left` on any block element (

, , etc.).

If you mean adding hyphens to words to break them to the next line and make the word-spacing prettier use Sweet Justice which works with jQuery or YUI.

http://carlos.bueno.org/2010/04/sweet-justice.html

Comment: The text has to be justified. The idea you suggested is probably the solution.
<br/>
Thanks,
~Vyee